# Why current does not flow in few branches of these circuits?

Tags: circuit-analysis

This is the first circuit, why there is no current in upper branch.

[image]

If you want a video which show the direction of the current you can check this  (http://srecorder.com/s/1ok4   (this link will provide you the video which contain the circuit)

.

The schematic diagram of the next circuit is this,

[image]

If you want to know the direction of current you can check this

http://srecorder.com/s/1ok3

In both the cases you might say potential difference is same  which ultimately pave the the path to stop the current flow which is a obvious thing,but I want to know why the potential difference are same ,if they are in the same node I could say potential difference is same , but neither of them are  posses that

Comment: Because ideal wires have no resistance.

Comment: -1 for expecting us to watch a video to see information that could be presented in a still image.

Comment: Post still images and I might consider looking.

Comment: The road appears long on the way to success.  Framed properly the people on this board will help, but a significant part of learning comes from finding your own answers.

Comment: Hello everyone, I thought that video would be better than a screen-shot, but I see It didn't go really well.However now I upload screen shots which should be helpfull

Answer (score 1):

In both cases the potential difference between the middle and the top is zero volts, therefore, there is not current flow (assuming ideal circuit).

Answer (score 1):

In both circuits there is a horizontal wire shorting out the branches. Current is not going to flow up and around the loop and through the resistors when there is a shortcut path with no resistance.

Another way of looking at it is that the three resistors can be combined in parallel...but wait! When you do that one end of the equivalent resistor isn't connected to anything. So you can see that even though the circuit looks like a loop, electrical it isn't.